# Integrating Alation Data Catalog with Tableau Data Catalog

Tags: tableau-api, catalog, alation

I have both my tableau catalog and also my alation data catalog (identifying tableau content as well), and am trying to insert the alation lineage for tableau into the tableau catalog so that it updates the descriptions/tags in Tableau. Also trying to move the tableau external asset into a project automatically.

This was already attempted previously by another developer but there are multiple data source duplicates and overall bad configuration. Wasn't able to find any documentation at all on this, anyone have any resources?